# All values in array bound to same value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to update values inside $scope.match.teams[0] with vaules for the players' names, but when I input in a single field, it is bound to every players' name for that team.

Controller:

```
$scope.match = {
        teams: [
            {
                id: 0,
                name: "",
                players: [
                    { id: 1, name: "" },
                    { id: 2, name: "" },
                    { id: 3, name: "" },
                    { id: 4, name: "" },
                    { id: 5, name: "" },
                    { id: 6, name: "" },
                    { id: 7, name: "" },
                    { id: 8, name: "" },
                    { id: 9, name: "" },
                    { id: 10, name: "" },
                    { id: 11, name: "" },
                ]
            },
            {
                id: 1,
                name: "",
                players: [
                    { id: 1, name: "" },
                    { id: 2, name: "" },
                    { id: 3, name: "" },
                    { id: 4, name: "" },
                    { id: 5, name: "" },
                    { id: 6, name: "" },
                    { id: 7, name: "" },
                    { id: 8, name: "" },
                    { id: 9, name: "" },
                    { id: 10, name: "" },
                    { id: 11, name: "" },
                ]
            }
        ]
    };

$scope.battingFirstSelected = function(){

    switch ($scope.battingFirst.id) {

        case 0:
            $scope.battingSecond = $scope.match.teams[1];

        case 1:
            $scope.battingSecond = $scope.match.teams[0];
    }
};
```

HTML:

```
      Team batting first:
      <select
        ng-change="battingFirstSelected()"
        ng-model="battingFirst"
        ng-options="team.name for team in match.teams">
      </select>

      <div ng-repeat="player in battingFirst.players">
        <input
          class="form-control"
          ng-model="match.teams[battingFirst.id].player.name"
          value="" />
      </div>

      <div ng-repeat="player in match.teams[battingFirst.id].players">
        {{ match.teams[battingFirst.id].player.name }}
      </div>
```

The selection of the team works fine, it's just assigning the names that's the problem here.

The output of `{{ match.teams[battingFirst.id] }}` shows that I'm creating a new team every time I fill in one of the inputs, with a `{ player: {"name":"sdf"} }` object attached to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to try:

`ng-model="player.name"`

Your `battingFirst` is already a selected team from the above select. When you bind to `players` in this `battingFirst`, you bind correctly to `players` of the selected team.

```
<div ng-repeat="player in battingFirst.players">
      <input
          class="form-control"
          ng-model="player.name"
          value="" />
  </div>
```

The problem you have is because ng-repeat **creates child scopes**. Therefore `match.teams` inside your ng-repeat **is not the same** as the `match.teams` of your parent scope.

Comment: Ah, of course. That works now. I'll accept this answer in 9 minutes when it allows me to.

Comment: @babbaggeii: added more explanation about your problem.